# python script hangs on input method when running spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a simple script by python in spark
when I use input method, running scripts stuck in that line
here is the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

testFileName = input("enter file name: ");
print("okey I'll open " + testFileName)
# load an RDD from a test file
fileRDD = sc.textFile(testFileName)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? The script will hang until an input is provided. If this is Python 2.7 then `input` will probably throw an error too, needing `raw_input` instead.

Comment: I mean I write the input in terminal and press the Enter key but scrip still is waiting for my input, no time out, no exception @roganjosh

Comment: I tried raw_input too but result was same as what was @roganjosh

Comment: So this is Python 2.7, in which case you definitely don't want `input`. Also, why do you have `;` at the end of `testFileName = input("enter file name: ")`?

Comment: How do you execute this? With `spark-submit`?

Comment: yes I use spark-submit in bin dir @LostInOverflow

Comment: sorry :) my bad. I'm java developer and use ; by default. I'll blend in future @roganjosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit application using `spark-submit` you don't interact with Python code, but with Java one, which doesn't expect any input from stdin.

If you want to make it work you have to skip `spark-submit` and execute this as a Python script directly.